# Android: Drawable Icon is invisible

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

I am trying to get a list of Apps installed on the Device and display them with their icon in a RecyclerView.

The following code is used to get the Apps:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> installedApps= packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

        installedApps.forEach(p-> {
            String appName = p.loadLabel(packageManager).toString();
            String appPackageName = p.activityInfo.packageName;
            Drawable icon = p.loadIcon(packageManager);
            ApplicationInfo info = p.activityInfo.applicationInfo;

            App_Object appObject = new App_Object(appName, appPackageName, icon, info);
            if(!List_AllApps.contains(appObject)) {
                List_AllApps.add(appObject);
            }
        });
        
List_AllApps.sort(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.app_name));
```

The problem here is, that some Drawables were invisible and could not be displayed, even though they were not null.

I found out that said Drawables do have an icon.getIntrinsicHeight() and an icon.getIntrinsicWidth() of 0, which resulted in them being invisible.

I already tried to convert the Drawables to ShapeDrawables, as you can use setIntrinsicWidth() and setIntrinsicHeight() there but I was not successful.
I also tried to set the bounds of the Drawables that did not display and also tried to convert them to BitmapDrawables but without any results.

The weird thing here is, that sometimes the icon gets displayed without any change done on the code, so it is really confusing to me what else I could try to fix this (getIntrinsicWidth() and getIntrinsicHeight() are then greater than 0 and have the desired value).

How is it possible to fix this issue? Can I resize them in any other way so they will get displayed?

Here a picture of what it looks like when setting the Drawable for the Imageview in the Recyclerview:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rL1M4.jpg)

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To display list of the apps installed on the device you can use GET_META_DATA of package manager.

```html
public void getInstalledApplication() {
  PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
  List < ApplicationInfo > packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
  //You have all list of packages in the device.
  for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo: packages) {
//Check if the application is updated or not
    if ((packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP) != 0) {
      addToInstalledApps(packageInfo, pm);
    } else if ((packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) {//This application is installed in the device system's image

    } else {
      addToInstalledApps(packageInfo, pm);
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can get appName and appIcon of the device. Below is the method.

```html
    public void addToInstalledApps(ApplicationInfo packageInfo, PackageManager pm) {
        int stringId = packageInfo.labelRes;
        String appName = null;
        Drawable appIcon = null;
        try {
            appName = (String) pm.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo);
            appIcon = pm.getApplicationIcon(packageInfo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                appName = stringId == 0 ? (packageInfo.nonLocalizedLabel != null ? packageInfo.nonLocalizedLabel.toString() : null) : getString(stringId);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName) != null && CommonUtil.isValidString(appName)){
        //Now you can design your model and insert data as you want.
            AppDetailsModel appDetailsModel = new AppDetailsModel(packageInfo.packageName, packageInfo.sourceDir, pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName), appName, appIcon);
            
            appDetailsModelList.add(appDetailsModel);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi Shubham, first of all thanks for your answer!

Unfortunetly this is not the solution for the problem i am facing.
I do get the information I need with my code but the problem is with the Drawable itself.

I also tried your code and it unfortunately produced the same result.

Comment: As you said drawable is not null. It may be size issue. Please do check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63739070/android-drawable-icon-is-invisible/63740946#63740946] . Hope it helps.